# Dependency Injection - interfaces in a Dictionary c#

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, interface, .net-6.0, idictionary

I want to inject a `IDictionary` of `{key, interface}` into a contructor, but I have no idea how to set it up in the `program.cs`

I can initiate the Interfaces and I can could initiate an `IDictionary` but I have no idea how to combine them.

Any suggestions would be appriciated.

Additional Context:

So i need to inject my services like

I need to inject the services eg,

```
s.AddTransient<IFooService, AFooService>();
s.AddTransient<IFooService, BFooService>();
```

but in the contructor I want

```
public MyClass(IDictionary<string, IFooService> fooServices)
```

Comment: `services.AddSingleton(myDictionary);`? Why do you want to do that in the first place though?

Comment: You shouldn't register a generic collection interface as a service. Why can't you define a normal service interface?

Comment: What would a dictionary of interfaces contain in the first place? If you mean to store interface types, you'd have to use a `Dictionary<whatever,Type>`. There's no way to say the types are interface, nor would it make a lot of sense. You can't instantiate instances of an interface. If you want to store instances that implement a specific interface you'd need `Dictionary<whatever,IMyInterface>`.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem X and assume Y is the solution (registering a dictionary of .... something). When that doesn't work, you ask for Y, not the real problem X. What is X here? Would it be solved if you registered services by name? That's already supported

Comment: I have added a bit more to the op, but i don't know how add the interfaces to a dictionary to inject it.

Comment: @EnenDaveyBoy what does `string` represent here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```cs
services.AddTransient<MyClass>();
services.AddTransient<AFooService>();
services.AddTransient<BFooService>();

services.AddTransient<IDictionary<string, IFooService>>(sp =>
    new Dictionary<string, IFooService>
    {
        { "A", sp.GetRequiredService<AFooService>() },
        { "B", sp.GetRequiredService<BFooService>() },
    });
``
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit intrusive alternative is to add a key property to `IFooService`. Then you can have MEDI enumerate services:

```cs
interface IFooService
{
    string FooKey { get; }
    // ... void Work(); ...
}

class MyClass
{
    private IDictionary<string, IFooService> fooServices;

    public MyClass(IEnumerable<IFooService> fooServices) 
    {
        this.fooServices = fooServices.ToDictionary(foo => foo.FooKey);
    }
}

class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IServiceCollection s) 
    {
        // you can keep the initialization as-is. DI will populate IEnumerable
        s.AddTransient<IFooService, AFooService>();
        s.AddTransient<IFooService, BFooService>();
    }
}
```

I like this approach because my app performs DI registration via reflection, so adding another `IFooService` is as simple as adding a new class file.